# Window not scrolling down in protractor automation script

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor

I written below script to scroll page down but its not working.

```
browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(400,700);').then(function()
{
//browser.sleep(6000);
var carouselTitle = element(by.css('[ng-if="accessoriesCarouselCtrl.showCarousal==true"]')).element(by.tagName('h3'));
return carouselTitle.getText().then(function(CarouselCPDP)
{
expect(CarouselCPDP).to.equal('carouselTitleJson');
browser.sleep(6000);

});

});
```

Comment: When you say it is not working, what kind of error do you get? Does it scroll? or does the test fail the expectation? Did you mean "showCarousel" (you spelled it showCarousal)? An element doesn't have to be scrolled into view for protractor to `getText` on the element.

Comment: As page gets loaded, page remains on top and do not scrolls down to mentioned coordinates. I just want to page scrolled down to focus element "var carouselTitle = element(by.css('[ng-if="accessoriesCarouselCtrl.showCarousal==true"]')).element(by.tagName('h3'));"

Answer (score 0):

You can use following to scroll to an element:

```
browser.driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(false);", element(YOUR_LOCATOR).getWebElement());
```

This code scrolls to an element, if needed. If you use this your code would look like:

```
browser.driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(false);", element(YOUR_LOCATOR).getWebElement()).then(function()
{
    //browser.sleep(6000);
    var carouselTitle = element(by.css('[ng-if="accessoriesCarouselCtrl.showCarousal==true"]')).element(by.tagName('h3'));
    return carouselTitle.getText().then(function(CarouselCPDP)
    {
        expect(CarouselCPDP).to.equal('carouselTitleJson');
        browser.sleep(6000);

    });

});
```

Comment: I used this code but still page not scrolling down. browser.driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(false);", element(by.css('.btn btn-primary ng-binding ng-scope')).getWebElement()).then(function()
   {
           //browser.sleep(6000);
   var carouselTitle = element(by.css('[ng-if="accessoriesCarouselCtrl.showCarousal==true"]')).element(by.tagName('h3'));
            return carouselTitle.getText().then(function(CarouselCPDP){
   console.log(CarouselCPDP);
           expect(CarouselCPDP).to.equal('carouselTitleJson');
   browser.sleep(6000);
   
   });
   
   });

Comment: Here is the element code: <button ng-if="!vm.isUserLoggedIn" type="button" role="button" class="btn btn-primary ng-binding ng-scope" ng-class="{'deactivate-button':selectedProductButtonEnabled(vm.productDetailsService.model.selectedProduct)}" ng-disabled="vm.disableCtaBtn" ng-click="vm.addDeviceToCart(vm.productDetailsService.model.selectedProduct,vm.productDetailsService.model.productCategoryType)" aria-label="Add to cart" ng-enter="vm.addDeviceToCart(vm.productDetailsService.model.selectedProduct,vm.productDetailsService.model.productCategoryType)">Add to cart</button>

Comment: Do you have more than one button with this css classes?
Please try following to get your element: 
`element(by.buttonText('Add to cart'))`

Comment: its also not working. In trouble to complete script :(

Comment: Please provide you current code and the error message.